# Faster Shuffling for a Simple Application

Tags: random-number-generator, anonymity, mental-poker

Alice, Bob, and Charlie are working on three projects.

Alice is the manager.  At the beginning of each day, she chooses one
project to work on (this choice is based on her preferences and is
not random) and then assigns the other projects to Bob and Charlie.
Bob and Charlie demand that this assignment be 50/50 random and
anonymous (so Alice does not know who got which of the two projects).
Alice accepts this demand, but demands that her original choice be
anonymous too (so Bob and Charlie can not know which project Alice
has, unless they tell each other their projects to deduce the remaining
project).

To accomplish this, at the beginning of each day, Alice writes the
two projects she does not want on two cards and puts them face down on
a table.  Everyone mixes/shuffles the cards until everyone is content
that no one knows which is which.  Bob picks a card, Charlie gets the
other card, and they then work separately on the projects written on
their cards.

---

The only way I see to accomplish this "at a distance with cryptography"
is [Mental Poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker), based on
a commuting encryption/decryption method:

```
Alice shuffles and encrypts both (starting from her two unwanted projects)
-> Bob shuffles and encrypts both
-> Charlie shuffles and encrypts both
-> Alice decrypts both
-> Bob decrypts the first and Charlie decrypts the second
-> In secret, Bob decrypts the second and Charlie decrypts the first
```

This is a lot of back and forth for every daily assignment - Is there any
simpler solution?

Ignoring Charlie, I was thinking Bob could give some seed (generated from a
private key) to Alice before everything and then Alice would generate random numbers for Bob (readable with his private key, but unreadable to
Alice) which somehow exclude Alice's project...but maybe that is a pipe
dream.

Comment: What about: Bob and Charlie broadcast commitments to random bits $b$ and $c$ respectively. *Then* Alice broadcasts the two messages/projects in plain in a random order. Bob and Charlie then send openings of their commitments to each other but not Alice. If $b\oplus c=0$, Bob takes the first project. Otherwise he takes the second one. That's 3 rounds of you have a broadcast channel.

Comment: @Maeher Bob and Charlie then will know Alice's project, but I want everyone to only know their own project.

Comment: I don't know if it can be done without lots of back and forth, but it seems that if this can be done then you can build from it a multi-party oblivious transfer where Alice is the sender, and Bob and Charlie are 2 parties that each selects a message from Alice without each party knowing what the other selected, but having both parties influencing their own outputs.

Comment: What are you trying to minimize? communication, conputation? what you suggested seems simple to me.

Comment: Let's say I want minimum computation time on x64 cores so that projects can be reassigned as fast as possible (instead of just daily).

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way is to use two oblivious transfers.  In case you need reminding: an Oblivious Transfer is a protocol where one party (Alice) has a number of secrets (in this case, two), and the other party (Bob or Charlie) gets to pick which one he gets to learn, but he doesn't learn the other (and Alice doesn't learn which one he picked).  There are several known protocols that implement this.

Here is how it would work:

Bob and Charlie randomly agree on a random bit $b$

Alice takes the two tasks she doesn't want, and randomly labels them $T_0$ and $T_1$

Bob then performs an oblivious transfer with Alice, obtaining the task $T_b$

Charlie then performs an oblivious transform with Alice (but using the bit $1-b$ rather than $b$ in the oblivious transfer), obtaining the task $T_{1-b}$

Because of the guarantees that OT provides, neither Alice, Bob nor Charlie know any of the tasks other than their own.

Now, one obvious issue is that, if Bob or Charlie wanted to cheat, they could use the wrong value of $b$, and learn the task given to the other guy.  However, if they did that, they wouldn't learn their own, and so if we assume that they find that unacceptable, this isn't an issue.  It is possible to insert a zero knowledge proof that would ensure that they're not doing that (the details of which would depend on the OT protocol used); however I don't know if you need to do that.

Comment: The "Mental Poker" method I gave does avoid the cheating issue you point out, but I'm willing to agree that no one would cheat like this.  It seems your method can reuse the same RSA keys every day (the "Mental Poker" method I gave needed to generate new RSA keys for all 3 parties every day!), so I like it.  I bet there's still a more efficient trick, so want to leave this question open for a few days before marking an answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem simpler, you just used a short name to a complex part (oblivious transfer).

Comment: @MeirMaor: in some sense, it is partially true (it does appear to simpler in total than mental poker); on the other hand, by encapsulating some of the complexity in already defined logic (which isn't that much more complicated than standard public key encryption), I would argue that the above description is much simpler...